# JFreeChart table in the X axis?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jfreechart

Do any of you know how to put a table in the X axis?

Something like this

[image: table chart]

It's basically a table with some values, and the ticks will have the sum of them. I probably know that this feature is not supported out-of-the-box, but maybe you could give me some pointers?

Thank you very much

Comment: `CrosshairDemo2` in the [JFreeChart Demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html) is a good example.

Comment: strange, I cannot see it.. am I missing something? I only see 12 examples

Comment: In the web start demo, it's one of the `*** Showcase Charts ***` and also appears under `Miscellaneous > Crosshairs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [highchart](http://www.highcharts.com), it is very powerful and may help finding the solution.

When I was making charts, using extjs4, and in particularly, water-fall chart, it took me about 2 days searching for a way to do it. And settled for using highchart which helped me solve my problem.